# Random logo in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create in jQuery a "wall" of logo like on the https://www.squarespace.com/ website at the "TRUSTED BY THE WORLD’S BEST" section.

The same thing : 8 logos with fade-in fade-out.

Can I have some help please ?

```
 <div class="client-logos-grid">
        <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
        <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt=""></a>
 </div>
```

I begin with this : https://jsfiddle.net/vc43mzxL/1/

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  var curIndex = 0;
  var src = ['http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg', 'http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg', 'http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg'];
  var fadeTimeInMilliseconds = 2000;
  var waitTimeInMilliseconds = 5000;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    switchImageAndWait(true);
  });

  function switchImageAndWait(fadeOut2) {
    if (fadeOut2) {
      setTimeout(fadeOut, waitTimeInMilliseconds);
    } else {
      var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * src.length))
      if (curIndex == index) {
        index++;
        if (index >= src.length) {
          index -= 8;
        }
      }
      curIndex = index;
      $(".client-logo img").attr("src", src[index]);
      fadeIn();
    }
  }

  function fadeOut() {
    $(".client-logo img").fadeTo(fadeTimeInMilliseconds, 0, function() {
      switchImageAndWait(false);
    });
  }

  function fadeIn() {
    $(".client-logo img").fadeTo(fadeTimeInMilliseconds, 1, function() {
      switchImageAndWait(true);
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten to add your JS code ..?

Comment: you need to provide your js code as well

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, but my comment is more polite way to express the idea. Which finally appeared to be a wrong assumption, OP seems to have an attempt.

Comment: @Jandon, please add your code to the question, not everybody likes to be forwarded to external sites simply to try and answer a question

Comment: @Icepickle, ok I updated my post

Comment: Just FYI, everyone - his alter ego is discussing the same question over here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45312592/1427878

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  //calling every 20 millseconds
  setInterval(function() {
    changeLogo();
  }, 200);
});

function changeLogo() {
  //taking first active logo
  var shownLogo = $(".client-logos-grid").find('.client-logo:not(.hidden)');
  var shownLogo = $(".client-logos-grid").find('.client-logo:not(.hidden)');
  shownLogo.fadeOut(200, function() {
    shownLogo.addClass('hidden');
    //check if its the last logo in the row
    if (shownLogo.next('.client-logo').length > 0) { // not last
      shownLogo.next('.client-logo').fadeIn(400, function() {
        shownLogo.next('.client-logo').removeClass('hidden');
      });

    } else { // last
      //move to first 
      $('.client-logo:first').fadeIn(400, function() {
        $('.client-logo:first').removeClass('hidden');
      });

    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="client-logos-grid">
  <a href="" class="client-logo"><img src="" alt="">A</a>
  <a href="" class="client-logo hidden hide"><img src="" alt="">B</a>
  <a href="" class="client-logo hidden hide"><img src="" alt="">C</a>
  <a href="" class="client-logo hidden hide"><img src="" alt="">D</a>
  <a href="" class="client-logo hidden hide"><img src="" alt="">E</a>
  <a href="" class="client-logo hidden hide"><img src="" alt="">F</a>
  <a href="" class="client-logo hidden hide"><img src="" alt="">G</a>
  <a href="" class="client-logo hidden hide"><img src="" alt="">H</a>
</div>
```

Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Still the transition from A to B takes a bit more time than others. I'm trying to sort it out. Any help from the community will be welcomed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed to give text to second anchor tag. Now its corrected.

Comment: Thank you ! I try to create the same system as  https://www.squarespace.com. 8 logos show and 1 replace randomly 1 logo

Answer (score 0):

i inspect their web and they use [their custom js](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/ta/5134cbefe4b0c6fb04df8065/9062/scripts/regions/HomeWinter2016.js) to animate the logo transition.

you can also do this by using [simplefadeslideshow](https://www.simplefadeslideshow.com)

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <li><a href="link1.html"><img src="images/4.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="" /></a></li> <!-- This is the last image in the slideshow -->
    <li><a href="link2.html"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.html"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0" alt="" /></a></li> <!-- This is the first image in the slideshow -->
</div>
```

and bind the plugin to the HTML structure you have created

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow();
});
```

the demo web can be seen [here](https://www.simplefadeslideshow.com/light-demo/) hope this helps