# Change one random image in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, shuffle

I would like to create a client's logo wall like this : https://www.squarespace.com/ scroll down until "TRUSTED BY THE WORLD’S BEST" section.

To create the same effect, I begin to generate a list of 8 elements and after I put random src image from an array inside my list : https://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/avn64tw0/6/

After that, I tried to change randomly ONLY ONE image after the other :
https://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/avn64tw0/8/

I don't know how to change only one random image ? And after add the little move effect to from the bottom to the top.

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-items"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-items {
    max-width: 500px;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    img {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
// List of images //
var logos = ["http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-1.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-2.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-3.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-4.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-5.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-6.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-7.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-8.jpg"];

// Generate 8 items //
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    $(".list-items").append('<a href="" class="item"><img src="" alt=""></a>');
}

// Shuffle function //
function shuffle(o) {
    for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

logos = shuffle(logos);

// Push src in image tags //
$('.item img').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('src', logos[i]);
});

// Change one image after the other //
count = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $(".item img").fadeOut(600, function () {
      $(this).attr('src', logos[count % logos.length]).fadeIn(600);
    });
 }, 5000);
```

The "Change image" part don't work like I would like, it change all the image while I would like one image after the other.

**UPDATE**

With help of @ChrisG I got an image who change randomly, but sometimes I got duplicate image.

https://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/avn64tw0/11/

Comment: Instead of `$(".item img").fadeOut(` use `$(".item img").eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)).fadeOut(` Avoiding duplicates gets a bit more complicated though.

Comment: Also note that this question isn't so much about changing images as it is about selecting a random element from a bunch of them. When you make sure not to post a duplicate before asking a question, always narrow it down to the actual issue first, and you will easier find existing solutions.

Comment: @ChrisG, Thank you for your answer, that's work but I have duplicate image.

Comment: What did you expect? You only have a total of eight images.

Comment: Keep cool @ChrisG !  Just tell me that I don't have enough image but don't not in this manner. I'm a beginner. I add two images more and that's the same issue !

Comment: You need at least sixteen images to make sure you never get duplicates.

Comment: @ChrisG, I got the same issue with 16 images

Comment: if you don't want duplicates, you can try having one array of all of the images and when one image is shown, push that image to another array. Do that until all the images are shown and then reset everything.

Comment: _"I'm a beginner. "_ - ah, same as your alter ego then, hm? ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298385/random-logo-in-a-grid

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/2zdvtkz3/1/ (I used a randomized img array to make sure all images are changed once per cycle)

Comment: You would only need 9 images to never have a duplicate O_o not 16

Comment: @BrandonBrickyKerr Nonsense. I had to substantially alter the code to make sure there are no duplicates, even with 16 images. If one of the images is not picked by the random function for more then 7 or 8 times, it will end up being a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random logo in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298385/random-logo-in-a-grid)

Comment: @CBroe - nice find! I never get why people create multiple accounts. I guess it could be marked as a duplicate then (*I just voted for it*).

Comment: @ChrisG it doesn't matter how many images you have to pull from, if you're not specifically forcing it to be a unique index you always have a chance of duplication. But as long as you have at least n+x many options, you can replace x many elements without a duplicate. Since OP wants to replace a single image, you only need a pool of 9 images to accomplish this.

Comment: @BrandonBrickyKerr I thought you were referring to the OP's way of selecting a new image. In general, 9 images are of course enough, yes.